# Sql query with an or statement takes too long to execute

Tags: sql, performance, oracle

I have a table with 2 columns - ref_table_id, ref_objid.
This table is used to reference objects in other tables. It has actually more than 2 columns but other columns are not important.

The following query takes 1 second to execute:

```
delete from ref_table_id
where (ref_table_id = 1 and 
       ref_objid not in (select objid from table1))
```

As well this query takes 1 second to execute:

```
delete from ref_table_id
where (ref_table_id = 2 and 
       ref_objid not in (select objid from table2))
```

However this query takes 3 minutes to execute:

```
delete from ref_table_id
where (ref_table_id = 1 and 
       ref_objid not in (select objid from table1))
   or (ref_table_id = 2 and 
       ref_objid not in (select objid from table2))
```

Why does the last query take so much time? It is basically just a combination of the first two. Can anyone please explain this?

I am using Oracle.

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you run an explain plan and see where the inefficiency lies ? I have a feeling that the OR statement means indexes aren't being used efficiently...

Comment: Are you able to see the query plan for all 3 queries?  It may help to identify where the problem is.

Comment: -1 For posting a performance question but not including the explain plan.  Without the explain plan this question will never help anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle is notoriously slow with `or` in `where` clauses. The reason being that indexes cannot be used as well in these conditions.

You'd best execute two separate `delete` statements in this case.

If you desperately want to do it in one statement, you may want to try this:

```
delete from ref_table_id
where
  id in 
    ( select id from ref_table_id
      where
        ref_table_id = 1 and 
        ref_objid not in (select objid from table1)
      union all
      select id from ref_table_id
      where
        ref_table_id = 2 and 
        ref_objid not in (select objid from table2) 
    )
```

The `union all` is very fast, and it eliminates the use of `or`. But on the other hand, it makes the statement more complex, so like I said, it may be much easier to just execute two deletes.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I already split the delete into multiple statements. I didn't know that indexes are not used with or. Can you provide a link to where this is explained please?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I know this from experience more than documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of reasons why an oracle query could take so long, but in this case I would guess:

1- the inner select (select objid from table1 and select objid from table2) will have to be evaluated on each row.

2- Due to stale statistics, oracle is creating a bad execution plan, try to gather fresh statistics.

3- try to index your columns included in joins.